# MainLauncher=true necessary and overrides RegisterAppStart<T>

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

Using MVVMCross, I want to start the app with the same view on all platforms. Using `RegisterAppStart<FirstViewModel>` in `App.cs` seems to be the correct way. But in Android it's necessary to define a View with `[Activity(Label = "First Screen", MainLauncher = true)]`. Otherwise Xamarin Studio show me following error: `No Launchable Activity Found`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself: We need to add a simple SplashScreen in Android. See [MVVMCross Docs](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/navigation) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You don't do anything wrong. Android needs a MainLauncher defined, whereas IOS don't (always starts at Main() ). Different OS, different requirements.

Comment: But this way, a custom app start (see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customizing-using-App-and-Setup#custom-imvxappstart) won't work on Android, right?

Comment: I am not sure how the app-start you link to is called by the framework on Android. If you can't get it working, you can try calling your linked code manually from your main launcher view and have that view as an empty view that does nothing.